# GoogleChart Need SlantedText for Horizontal Axis or hAxis

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to generate the column chart by following the GoogleChart documentation at the URL: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart , My requirement is to tilt the horizontal axis upto 45 degree so that when the number of columns increases the label of each column still will be visible properly currently if I decrease the width from 800 to 400. The labels of each bar is not visible. Attaching the URL of

```
    [https://jsfiddle.net/ashoksinghnegi/L72d3yxo/3/][2]
```

so that you can have a look on it.

In the documentation it is written that it can be achieved by adding the attribute like as shown below hAxis: {**slantedText**:true,**slantedTextAngle**:45}

But still I am not able to do that. Please suggest what I should I do to achieve it.

Comment: URL for jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ashoksinghnegi/L72d3yxo/3/

Comment: you are using a _material_ chart, there are several options that are not supported by _material_ charts. see [this issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) for more info...